# Facelet include of a servlet generated content

Tags: jsf, servlets, facelets

I'd like to include a servlet generated content in a facelet using ui:include. So far I only got errors.

Note that the servlet works fine, GET requests from a browser are ok.

Note that I can successfully include content from another facelet file, but not when the content is servlet generated.

I googled and stackoverflowed my issue but could not find matching responses.

myfacelet.xhtml (at the root of the webapp, i.e. reached by "http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/myfacelet.xhtml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
  <title>JSF Dynamic Content</title>
</h:head><h:body>
  <h3>Dynamic content:</h3>
  <ui:include src="dynamic-content"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

MyServlet.java (can be reached by "http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/dynamic-content"):

```
@WebServlet(name = "DynamicContentServlet", urlPatterns = {"/dynamic-content"})
public class DynamicContentServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("<p>Dynamic stuff</p>");
  }
}
```

web.xml (JSF related stuff only) :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For ui:include="/dynamic-content" and urlPatterns="/dynamic-content"
(or ui:include="/mywebapp/dynamic-content" and urlPatterns="/dynamic-content")
the error is:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /myfacelet.xhtml @12,48 <ui:include src="/dynamic-content"> Invalid path : /dynamic-content
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:152)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
(...)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

For ui:include="dynamic-content" and urlPatterns="/dynamic-content"
or ui:include="dynamic-content.bla" and urlPatterns="*.bla",
the error is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
at org.apache.naming.resources.DirContextURLConnection.getInputStream(DirContextURLConnection.java:369)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache._getLastModified(DefaultFaceletCache.java:172)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.access$000(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:62)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:256)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:366)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:147)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
(...)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Also note that the servlet never gets executed.

What is wrong with my code?

Is the include possible?

How can I achieve it?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ui:include>` can only include another Facelets file, not the output of a JSP/Servlet.

You'd either need to replace the Servlet by a fullworthy Facelets file, or to use a Facelets tag file or a Facelets composite component wherein the HTML can also be generated dynamically using JSTL tags or the `rendered` attribute, if necessary with help of a backing bean or a backing component.

If you absolutely need to use a Servlet for some reason, for example because you're in a migration process from legacy JSP/Servlet to JSF/Facelets and don't have much time left to properly transform to the Servlet to a sane Facelets approach, then you can also consider to use [`<o:resourceInclude>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude) component of [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org):

```
<o:resourceInclude path="/dynamic-content" />
```

But as said, this isn't the right design approach. For a proper long term solution, you should look into replacing the Servlet by a Facelets file/tag/composite.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I may open a dedicated question to get proper design information. For now I focus on the "include servlet generated content" issue. :) I could not find technical information about this "ui:include" limitation. I even found sources that state that it is possible. :/ Do you have sources/explanations/specs about the limitation?

Comment: Just check tag documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html

Comment: That's one of the sources I refer to. From this documentation I understand that any XHTML file can be included, not just facelets. :'(

Comment: *"There are three things this tag can include: plain XHTML, and XHTML pages that have either a composition tag or a component tag."* A servlet is not among them.

Comment: Apples and oranges to me. "plain XHTML" is a content format while "servlet" is a tool to generate web content. My understanding of the documentation is that it imposes a restriction on the format, but not how it was generated. Hence including XHTML content generated from a servlet should be ok. To check this I ran another test.

Comment: I used 'ui:include src="http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/dynamic-content"'. Now it works, the inclusion is executed! There is something really fishy in "ui:include". I suspect that for relative (such as "bla/bli.xhtml") or absolute (such as "/bla/bli.xhtml") URLs, JSF checks if the target URL is an existing facelet (if not, then error). On the other hand, for "full" URL (such as "http://host:port/app/bla/bli") it does not, and the inclusion just works. What do you think? Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I too am developing an app that must perform dynamic page generation including embedded images,  `<map>` and `<area>` tags and associated `<div>` tags which highlight on rollover.

My naive first test approach was to just write out the entire html from a StringBuffer:  `response.getWriter().println(sb.toString());`.  This worked, but it's a hack, and does not take advantage of my JSF template.  Nor does it use the template even if I write out an entire `<ui:composition>` element.

In the Java EE 6 tutorial, there is detailed information on how to create a custom component.  See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glpcb.html

This seems to support BalusC's comment above, 
*"...use a Facelets tag file or a Facelets composite component wherein the HTML can also be generated dynamically using JSTL tags or the rendered attribute, if necessary with help of a backing bean or a backing component."*

Your mileage may vary!

Answer (score 0):

It has bean a while since the question is posted, but someone may find it useful, and I welcome your corrections if I did something stupid! 
I encountered the same issue, I solved it with a workout through javascript, the clues I used was from this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp , my servlet was to generate a map tag dynamically and it was set up on (web.xml) file with servlet filter (contours), so I applied the link in xhtml using the javascript from above mentioned link, (note: the rtutil.appUrl returns the context path of my JSF applicaiton), I applied it as follows:

```
<div w3-include-html="#{rtutil.appUrl}/contours/map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/rtscript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            includeHTML();
            $(document).ready(function () {
                cityplanmap();
            });
        </script>
```